# C#: Find tables involved in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Given a SQL query variable, i.e.,

```
string mySQLQuery = "SELECT TableA.Field1, TableA.Field2,..., TableB.Field1, TableB.Field2,.... FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Field1 = TableB.Field1"
```

Is there any straight way I can extract the fields and the table names within the query in two lists? so:

List "Fields":

- All fields From table A, table B (and others I could add by joining) with their table prefix (even if there were only one table in a simple 'SELECT * FROM TableA', I'd still need the 'TableA.' prefix).
- All fields From table B with their table prefix, by adding them to the list in the usual fieldList.Add() way through looping.

List "Tables":

- All tables involved in the query in the usual tablesList.Add() way through looping.

My first approach would be to make a lot of substrings and comparisons, i.e., finding the FROM, then trimming left, the substring until the first blank space, then the JOIN, then trimming, then the first substring until the space..., but that doesn't seem the right way.

**REEDIT**

I know I can get all the fields from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS with all the properties (that comes later), but the problem is that for that query I need the tables to be known. My steps should be:

1. The query "SELECT [fields] FROM [tables]" comes from a Multiline Textbox so I can write a SQL Query to fetch the fields I'd like. I take the string by txtMyQuery.Text property.
2. Find the field in the SELECT query, and find what table belongs to in the FROM clause.
3. Store the field like [Table].[Field]in a string list List strFields = new List() by the strFields.Add() method;
4. Then, iterate through the list in a way like:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < fieldList.Count; i++)
   {
      string mySqlQuery = "SELECT Table_Name, Column_Name, Data_Type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE (COLUMN_NAME + "." + TABLE_NAME) ='" + fieldList[i] + "'";

     //Commit query, get results in a gridview, etc.

   }
   ```

Comment: Parsing sql is similar complex than parsing HTML. I would look if there is a library evailable. I haven't found one that is free. Just this: http://www.sqlparser.com/

Comment: What should the output be if the sql statement is 'SELECT * FROM TableA'? Do you also need the fields in the JOIN and WHERE clause, or only those in the SELECT clause?
What happens if the statement is 'SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON(TableA.BId = TableB.Id)'?

Comment: I'd only need the fields in the SELECT clause to store them in a list. WHERE, HAVING, etc., are not needed even if there is a reference to another table without fields in the SELECT clause like you suggested.
In case of SELECT * FROM Table A, I'd need an output with TableA.Field1, TableA.Field2, TableA.Field3,...

Comment: Obviously you can't get the list of fields from a query such as 'SELECT * FROM Table A' without going to the actual table in the database and get the fields from there. However, you say you only need the fields that are actually selected, therefor you can't simply ask the database for all columns of all tables involved in the query. Sorry, but I don't see an easy way to do it...

Comment: Selected fields in a given query could be gotten by using a datareader and using that for schema information. Tables would likely need to be parsed out of the SQL

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

Tables:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
```

Fields:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Your Table'
```

Comment: see reedit... the problem is that 'Your table' need to be extracted

Comment: Ok, then I think the only solution is make your own parser or search for one made.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a while, I found SOME way to make this happen... I will work this out as I improve the solution (i.e., now it doesn't work if we use * selections like 'SELECT * FROM TableA', doesn't support aliasing, and all fields in the SELECT should be [table].[field], but will give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve):

This way, I write an SQL statement in a textbox, I pass it onto a new form to check the actual results of the query (if I needed, by clicking on a button "Preview"), and I populate a datagridview with the SCHEMA data I wanted to retrieve.

Thanks to all for your support!

```
 private void btnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string strSql = this.txtQuery.Text;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        String conStr = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            //with the call to strSQLSchema, we get the table involved in the query, to retrieve the fields and properties
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQLSchema(strSql), conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            try
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        this.dgvColumns.DataSource = dt;

    }

    private void btnPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //We must pass the sql query to preview
        string strSql = this.txtQuery.Text;
        SQLQueryDataPreview qp = new SQLQueryDataPreview(strSql);
        qp.Show();
    }

    private string strSQLSchema(string sqlQuery)
    {
        //we cut the "SELECT " start
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.ToUpper();
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Substring(7);
        //we take all the fields until the FROM
        int myIndex = sqlQuery.IndexOf("FROM");

        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Substring(0, myIndex);
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Trim();
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);

        //Here we add all fields to a list... so far, "*" is not allowed, and all fields should be written [Table].[Name]
        string[] myFields = sqlQuery.Split(new char[] {' ', ','});

        List <string> myTables = new List<string>();

        //We will use this WHERE to find the fields in the SCHEMA. This WHERE first sentence helps to construct a valid where
        //and avoid problems with the 'OR' clause in each loop.

        string myWhere = "TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME = ''";

        for (int i = 0; i < myFields.Count(); i++)
        {
            //here we take the table prefix and add it to an array
            int tableIndex = myFields[i].IndexOf(".");
            if (tableIndex != -1)
            {
                myTables.Add(myFields[i].Substring(0, tableIndex));
                myWhere += "OR (TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME = '" + myFields[i] + "')";
            }               
        }

        //this is a List where we keep the tables derivated from names. We just copy the list generated before with a DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates.
        myTables = myTables.Distinct().ToList();

        string schema = "SELECT Table_Name, Column_Name, Data_Type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE " + myWhere;
        return schema;
    }

}
```